# PHP session id of logged user

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a little problem with my php script. I built loging and register system. When database found a match user login and password, it set a session variable called "id_user" because i have to know which user is logged now.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='$login_cln' AND password='$haslo_cln'";
        if ($result = mysqli_query($link,$sql))
        {
            $count_user = $result->num_rows;
            if($count_user>0)
            {
                $_SESSION['logged'] = true;

                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['id_user'] = $row['id'];
```

okey, it working in my script for adding new text in my page:

```
$id= $_SESSION['id_user'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO pasta SET
        text="' . $tekst . '",
        author="' . $autor . '",
        datepasta=NOW(),
        title="' . $tytul . '",
        idauthor="' .$id.'"';
```

As you can see, i created a row called idauthor used for relation with user table. My problem start here. When one person is logged and he add a new text, database show correctly id of user in idauthor row. But when i have TWO people logged in, and they want to add a new text, my database shows id = 0 (in one case i saw a NULL text in a row). Why i have this problem? Thank you for any tips! Regards and sorry for my grammar.

Comment: Funny that it works the first time, `text` is a reserved word in mysql. Apart from that it is not clear what you are doing, is this all in the same script, are the sessions opened succesfully in all scripts, have you checked the values of your variables, etc.? And you should use a prepared statement as you are possibly sql injecting yourself.

Comment: I changed names of variables from polish to english.

Comment: Yes, i have opened session in all pages. It seems that i am losing  values of my variables when second user is logged in.